# Accumulating memory after forcing refresh method

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, bootstrapper

I have an application, connecting to some databases. After first execution the app takes 300Mb(some data is loading from databases),  and it's OK. But after pushing button "Refresh" refresh-method is called, in which I reassign old collections with new ones and the problem is that they after loading new data - old data is still taking memory, so after some forced resfreshes it can take up to 2Gb.

I've tried to force GC with different options - nothing happened. GC doesn't think that my collections need to be fully updated and old data must be destroyed.

I've decided to make my own Disposable collection, which inherits from List or Collection and implements IDisposable[1]. Then I've gone throw all classes, which contain in such collections and implemented IDisposable(with and without destructors), too.

I've used using() construction to clear those collections[2], but the result was that collections have become empty,  but still have taken memory.

Using profiling program, I saw that Gen0 objects amount grows each time I do refreshing. After 10 refreshes there were from 120 to 580 such objects, which GC couldn't clear.

EDIT:

3. DataContext.
4. UnitOfWork.
5. Repostitory.
6. Registration of repository and service of repository.
7. Method in service for getting data.
8. Declaring service using Bootstrapper and using it to get the data.

So 8 is in Refresh method,  and data is reassignes each refresh.

[1]

```
    public class DisposableList<T> : List<T>, IDisposable where T : 
IDisposable
{
    public DisposableList()
    {

    }

    public DisposableList(T instance)
    {
        Add(instance);
    }

    public DisposableList(IEnumerable<T> instances)
    {
        AddRange(instances);
    }

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            foreach (T item in this)
            {
                item.Dispose();
            }
        }
    }
    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
    }

    ~DisposableList()
    {

    }
}
```

[2]

```
using (Resources = new DisposableList<Resources>())
     {

     }
```

[3]

```
public partial class MyDataContext : DbContext, IMyDataContext
{
    static MyDataContext()
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<MyDataContext>(null);
    }

    public MyDataContext(string connectionString)
        : base(connectionString)
    {
        try
        {
            if (!Database.Exists())
            {
                throw new Exception($"Нет соединения с базой данных 
                                   {Database.Connection.Database}");
            }                
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
     }

     public IDbSet<Table> Table { get; set; }
 }
```

[4]

```
public class UnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork
     {
        DbContext _dataContext;
        IRepository[] _repositories;
        readonly object _locked = new object();

public UnitOfWork(DbContext dataContext, params IRepository[] 
                                                    repositories)
    {
        _dataContext = dataContext;
        _repositories = repositories;

    EFContextHelper.SetContext(_repositories, dataContext);
  }   


 public virtual void SaveChanges()
  {
      try
      {
          lock (_locked)
            {
                _dataContext.SaveChanges();
            }
      }
      catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException ex)
      {
          throw;
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
          throw;
      }
  }

  public virtual bool HasChanges()
    => _dataContext.ChangeTracker.HasChanges();

  public virtual void Rollback()
  {
      lock (_locked)
      {
          foreach (DbEntityEntry entry in 
                   _dataContext.ChangeTracker.Entries())
          {
  switch (entry.State)
  {
     case EntityState.Detached: break;
     case EntityState.Unchanged: break;
     case EntityState.Added:
         entry.State = EntityState.Detached;
         break;
     case EntityState.Deleted:
         entry.State = EntityState.Unchanged;
         break;
     case EntityState.Modified:
        entry.CurrentValues.SetValues(entry.OriginalValues);
        entry.State = EntityState.Unchanged;
        break;
     default:
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
  }

          }
       }
   }

#region IDispose

    bool _disposed;
    public virtual void Dispose()
    {
        if (_disposed) { return; }

        foreach (var repo in _repositories)
        {
            repo.Dispose();
        }

        _dataContext?.Dispose();
        _dataContext = null;

        _disposed = true;
    }
```

[5]

```
public interface IRepository<TEntity> : IRepository where TEntity : class
{
    TEntity Create();
    void Delete(TEntity entity);
    void Delete(IEnumerable<TEntity> entities);
    void AddOrUpdate(TEntity entity);
    void Attach(TEntity entity);
    void Reload(TEntity entity);
    void Detach(TEntity entity);
}
```

[6]

```
builder.RegisterType<Service>().As<IService>();
builder.RegisterType<Repository>).As<Repository>;
```

[7]

```
GetData()
{    
   using (_UnitOfWorkFactory.Create(_repository))
    {
         var data = _repository.Get();
    }
}
```

[8]

```
var service = Bootstrapper.Container.Resolve<IService>();
var data = service.GetData();
```

So I need my app to use such amount of memory, which is used after first execution. I want my old data to be destroyed and new data to take old data place.

Comment: The Disposable route should not be necessary, I doubt it will help. What matters is how you manage your DbContext. We can't see any of that.

Comment: Looks as XY problem, you showed your solution, not your problem. Please provide your code where you fill collections with data from DB.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with collections. They don't need disposing. If you have leftover data after a GC it means the data is still in use and can't be collected.

Comment: Yes, but how to tell GC that object is not in use and it can be collected?

Comment: On the other hand, there's a *lot* wrong with the "generic repository" antipattern, or trying to use database transactions as units of work. A DbContext is a *higher level* abstraction compared to the generic repository. A UoW has nothing to do with databases nor should it care. In this case you are using UoW as if it were a repository because the *repository* prevents you from using a DbContext with multiple entities

Comment: OK, I could give you another example without databases. Imagine class with destructor and List<int> field. I create the instance of such object and 999999 times fill the list with 999999,  so the app takes some memory. Then I try to destroy the object in different ways,  which were described upper,  and nothing happens: the app still takes such amount of memory.

Comment: Then I'd say no repro without even trying anything. If you call `GC.Collect()` after filling the list *and* exiting its scope, it will be collected, because it's no longer used. If you try to add ints 999999  times though, you'd also get a *ton* of temporary buffers that can easily lead to an OutOfMemoryException. A List stores data in a buffer that gets reallocated when it runs out of space by assigning a new buffer twice as large. Do that 999999  times and you get 19 reallocations. Plus, large buffers come from the large object heap which lives for longer. You'd have to call `GC.Collect(2)`

Comment: You can easily find out what's going on in Visual Studio if you open the `Diagnostics` window while debugging and check the Memory graph. I suspect you'll see memory rising a *lot* as you load data and add it to columns item by item. You'll probably see a sawtooth shape too, as the garbage gets collected each time the GC runs. You can take memory snapshots at different times and compare them to see which objects got allocated since the last time

Comment: Other strong smells - the `lock` around `SaveChanges` suggests unsafe threading. A DbContext isn't thread safe. It represents a *single session's* data. It's one unit of work. Even if the thread-safe `SaveChangesAsync` method is used, what is the *second* call going to save? The changes were already saved by the first call!